# MySQL intersection

Tags: mysql, sql, select, intersection

I've an existing site, whose DB is not designed correctly and contains lot of records, so we cant change DB structure.

Database for current issue mainly contains 4 tables, users, questions, options and answers. There is standard set of questions and options but for each user, there is one row in answers table for each set of question and options. DB structure and example data is available at [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdc9/6).

Now as a new requirement of advanced search, I need to find users by applying multiple search filters. Example input and expected output is given in comments on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdc9/6).

I tried to apply all type of joins, intersection but it always fail somehow. Can someone please help me to write correct query, preferably light weight/optimized joins as DB contain lot of records (10000+ users, 100+ questions, 500+ options and 500000+ records in answers table)?

**EDIT: Based on two answers, I used following query**

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM users u
    JOIN answers a ON a.user_id = u.id
WHERE (a.question_id = 1 AND a.option_id IN (3, 5))
    OR (a.question_id = 2 AND a.option_id IN (8))
GROUP BY u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN (a.question_id = 1 AND a.option_id IN (3, 5)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >=1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN (a.question_id = 2 AND a.option_id IN (8)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1;
```

**Please note:** On real database, columns `user_id`, `question_id` and `option_id` of `answers` table are indexed.

Running query given on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdc9/46).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdc9/43) for dnoeth's answer.

[SQL Foddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdc9/45) for calcinai's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all you **n** filters into the WHERE using OR and repeat them in a HAVING(SUM(CASE)) using AND:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM users u JOIN answers a
  ON a.user_id = u.id
JOIN questions q
  ON a.question_id = q.id
JOIN question_options o
  ON a.option_id = o.id
WHERE (q.question = 'Language known' AND o.OPTION IN ('French','Russian'))
   OR (q.question = 'height' AND o.OPTION = '1.51 - 1.7')
GROUP BY u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
HAVING
  SUM(CASE WHEN (q.question = 'Language known' AND o.OPTION IN ('French','Russian')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >=1
AND 
  SUM(CASE WHEN (q.question = 'height'         AND o.OPTION = '1.51 - 1.7')          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
;
```

I changed your joins into the more readable Standard SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth , +1 for working query. I must admit that as of now, I do not understand what you wrote after `HAVING`. I must go through docs a bit. I'll apply your and @calcinai andwer and will accept which ever is more optimized. Thanks a lot once again for answer and more important, a new thing for me (SUM/CASE WHEN etc)

Comment: @Kapil Sharma: Of course my version is more efficient :-)  It's easy to add additional conditions, add a new condition to WHERE/HAVING instead of another join. Regarding the logic: check if each condition evaluates to TRUE at least once

Comment: I too feel so as in real time, there could be 30-50 filters and 30-50 joins would obviously kill DB server, specially when query happens too often. Still we need to implement some benchmark on real DB with 500000+ records. Please give me some time, it might take couple of hours more. I'd have accepted both answers but SO don't allow that.

Comment: I am curious to know the results of your benchmarking.  I agree that @dnoeth's query will probably be faster on the given data set, but I think it will crumble when there's a decent amount of data. There's an overhead of having `INNER JOINS`, but I think it will be pale in significance to that of creating a huge derived table and then performing a `HAVING` on an inherently unindexable column.

Comment: If the tables are properly indexed and each individual select will use index-based access or if the number of rows is reduced quickly (high selectivity) it might be faster.

Comment: For simple queries given on SQL fiddle, @calcinai query is faster and that can be confirmed even through SQL Fiddle. However my real DB is properly indexed and I'm searching through keys, not text. So with that dnoeth's query is faster on average. User may apply one filter or maximum of 50 filters, it depends on user but if user apply maximum allowed 50 filters, dnoeth's query is comparatively faster but still too slow. For now, going with dnoeth's query but I'd to return some day for DB optimization. Not giving benchmark numbers as my dev-box running on WAMP is not ideal for benchmark test.

Comment: That's interesting, I did a couple of tests and mine was 6x faster on 50k synthetic answers, each query adjusted to have 5 criteria. The only thing different to the fiddle was the 3 column index I was talking about earlier.

Comment: @calcinai: Did you consider that your query doesn't join to the options but uses option IDs instead? IMHO performance is mainly based on the cleverness of the optimizer and MySQL is not really advanced in that area :-)

Comment: @calcinai Well actually I didn't took dnoeth's answer as it is. there are only two tables used as in your answer as answers table have both question_id and option_id. So real query happens only on id as you suggested. Ideally I mixed your and dnoeth's answer. Please dont feel bad as I said my machine is not ideal for benchmark, probably my test might be wrong. I really appreciate your ans and it helped me a lot. I really owe both of you. As per rules I'd to accept one ans otherwise for me, both answers are accepted and my final query is mix of both.

Comment: @Kapil Sharma: Then you can do the GROUP/HAVING only on the answers table and join this result as a Derived Table back to users.

Comment: Yes I put conditions like `a.question_id = 5 AND a.option_id IN (2,3)`. As query output, I need data only from user table so just two tables joined, user and answer.

Comment: Sorry for asking again: Did you SELECT ... FROM users JOIN (SELECT a.user_id.. FROM answers HAVING...) ON...? You can do the same approach for calcinai query...

Comment: Hey sorry for late work. I updated the question with final query I used.

Answer (score 1):

This will require a bit of fiddling for a dynamic filter, but what you really want to do is search by the IDs, as it'll mean less joins and a faster query.

This produces the results you'd expect.  I assume that the search filters are generated based off options in the database, so instead of passing the actual value back in to the query, pass the ID instead.

The multiple inner joins are to support multiple AND criteria and auto-reduce your result set.

```
SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN answers a ON a.user_id = u.id
  AND (a.question_id, a.option_id) IN ((1,3),(1,5)) # q 1: Lang, answer 3/5: En/Ru
INNER JOIN answers a2 ON a2.user_id = u.id
  AND (a2.question_id, a2.option_id) = (2,8) # q 2: Height, answer 8: 1.71...
GROUP BY u.id;
```

I'd suggest making sure there's an index on (user_id, question_id, option_id) for searching:

```
ALTER TABLE `answers` ADD INDEX idx_search(`user_id`, `question_id`, `option_id`);
```

Otherwise it should be using primary keys for the joins (if properly defined) so it will be fast.

Comment: Thanks for answer @calcinai +1 , yes all FK columns are indexed and I'm passing ids, not values. On fiddle, I try to make a complex problem simple. One question, what do you mean by 'i' in Group by?

Comment: That was a typo.  My stupid computer auto-correcting 'u' to 'i'!

Comment: Gt8. Thanks a lot. Its working on simple fiddle example. Let me try that to original DB. I'll get back in case of any issue. Thanks again.